# Show Tkinter Window With overideredirect(True) in Doc Mac

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

When I use `root.overideredirect(True)`, I can't see window in the menu that pops up when I right click python doc/taskbar icon mac.

The code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.overideredirect(True) # Makes window not popup in right click doc menu

root.mainloop()
```

I want to keep the window in the menu, but get rid of the titlebar.